# Google Geocoding Weirdness

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I am having a weird problem. Suddenly my PHP implementation of the Google Geocoding API has simply decided to stop working. It now returns error 602 for every request, meaning address unavailable. But, if I open the actual url I am querying, it works perfectly and I can download the correct information. But if I use curl to grab it, 602 is returned instead of 200.

I have tried changing the API key, as well as checking and testing the url.

Comment: Are you running your PHP server locally for this test? Are the two requests coming from the same machine, is my question.

Comment: If I open the URL, its from my local machine, the curl request is from another machine. The only weird thing is that for about 5 months it has worked perfectly without any changes. And the URL still works, but when that machine grabs it using curl, just returns 602.

Comment: The thing is, testing the URL in your browser on your own computer is only half a test. The server could have some kind of proxy on it, be on some kind of blacklist, or have some other configuration consideration ... at this point, if I were you, I'd hit the Google boards.

Comment: I ran into a similar situation when I sent a viewport in a projected coordinate system.  Are you using any additional parameters?

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I'm currently experiencing exactly the same problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I used to add my country ("Australia") into the geocoding search string to limit free-form text searching to a 'local' address. This seemed to kill it.

```
geocoder.geocode(event.arg + "Australia");
```

Now i add this in the constructor (Actionscript, but probably applies to other languages)

```
var geocoder:ClientGeocoder = new ClientGeocoder(
            new ClientGeocoderOptions({
                countryCode: "AU",
                language: 'en'/
            }));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following method to geocode.  You could try it out just to make sure that it's not a cURL problem.

```
$request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($address);
$xml_string = file_get_contents($request_url);
$xml_string = str_replace('xmlns=', 'ns=', $xml_string);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
```

Also, if you haven't seen [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=80200&topic=11364) on geocoding with PHP, be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late reply.

According to http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/,

A Maps API key is no longer required.

> Note: The Google Geocoding API no
>   longer requires a Maps API key! Google
>   Maps API Premier customers must
>   additionally sign their URLs using a
>   new cryptographic key.

There is a limit though.

> Use of the Google Geocoding API is
>   subject to a query limit of 2,500
>   geolocation requests per day. (User of
>   Google Maps API Premier may perform up
>   to 100,000 requests per day.) This
>   limit is enforced to prevent abuse
>   and/or repurposing of the Geocoding
>   API, and this limit may be changed in
>   the future without notice.
>   Additionally, we enforce a request
>   rate limit to prevent abuse of the
>   service. If you exceed the 24-hour
>   limit or otherwise abuse the service,
>   the Geocoding API may stop working for
>   you temporarily. If you continue to
>   exceed this limit, your access to the
>   Geocoding API may be blocked.

The workaround to the limit is to request geocodes using many proxies simultaneously. If you have 10 proxies with different IP addresses, you can request 25000 geocodes daily.

Answer (score 0):

It returns 602 if it fails to geocode the address that it is trying.

Comment: It fails for every address, but every one of the addresses it fails for, if I just browse the url I am grabbing from curl, works fine.

Comment: Could be a mismatch on your api key possibly.  Do you have sensor set to false?

Answer (score 0):

Google now enforces valid key in your request so make sure you specify

```
&key=YOUR_VALID_KEY&sensor=false
```

in your request.

If you don't pass a valid key you'll get 602.